# Unknown people posting on my Facebook page

Tags: facebook

I am receiving posts of a person I do not know.  I believe it may have been a mistake and I messaged her to tell her to stop posting to me.  I have no idea who this person is.  The posts are annoying and cluttering up my page.

Comment: Are you talking about a Facebook page, or your timeline?

Answer (score 4):

### <sup>How do I block someone?</sup>

To block someone:

1. Click [image] at the top right of any Facebook page.
2. Click **How do I stop someone from bothering me?**
3. Enter the name or email address of the person you want to block and click **Block**.
4. If you entered a name, select the specific person you want to block from the list that appears.

People will not be notified when you block them.

If you can't find someone using this method, try going to the person's profile and selecting **Block** from the <kbd>**...**</kbd> menu on their cover photo.

If you still can't find the person you want to block, it's possible that this person no longer uses Facebook or has restricted their privacy settings. Keep in mind that you can always [control the audience of stuff](https://www.facebook.com/help/393920637330807) you share.

<sub>**Source:** https://www.facebook.com/help/168009843260943</sub>